# Ball not rolling properly CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

My animation works quite nicely but it seems its slipping and doesn't seem to roll. What could be the problem?

FIDDLE HERE : http://jsfiddle.net/erkoda3m/2/

```css
img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  animation: roll 4s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: roll 4s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes roll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(300px) rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes roll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(300px) rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/5NvOwB5.png">
```

Comment: Yes its rollin' properly!

Comment: No, it seems its slipping

Comment: All . Firefox and Chrome latest ones.

Comment: I got your question. Use pi * diameter of ball for translatex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The diameter is **150px**, so circumference will be **150π** = **471.24px**. So if the rotation angle is **360°**, translateX value will be circumference of the ball, or **471.24px** :

```css
img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  animation: roll 4s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: roll 4s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes roll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(471.24px) rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes roll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(471.24px) rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/5NvOwB5.png">
```

If you want to keep `translateX` constant and change `rotate` value, instead, you can calculate the angle by `(400/471.24)*360` = **305.57deg**

```css
img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  animation: roll 4s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: roll 4s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes roll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(400px) rotate(305.57deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes roll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(400px) rotate(305.57deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/5NvOwB5.png">
```